# How to record the mouse movement until a key is pressed with Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I want to make the function `mouse.record()` run until a key is pressed, rather than a mouse button. 
The `mouse.record()` is a function from the python module `mouse`:
(`mouse/__init__.py`)

```py
def record(button=RIGHT, target_types=(DOWN,)):
    """
    Records all mouse events until the user presses the given button. Then returns the list of events recorded. Pairs well with `play(events)`.

    Note: this is a blocking function. Note: for more details on the mouse hook and events see `hook`.
    """
    recorded = []
    hook(recorded.append)
    wait(button=button, target_types=target_types)
    unhook(recorded.append)
    return recorded
```

I've thought that I could merge the `mouse` module with the `keyboard` module to achieve a function that records the mouse movement until a keyboard event. There is a similar keyboard function that could be handy: 
(`keyboard/__init__.py`)

```py
def record(until='escape', suppress=False, trigger_on_release=False):
    """
    Records all keyboard events from all keyboards until the user presses the given hotkey. Then returns the list of events recorded, of type `keyboard.KeyboardEvent`. Pairs well with `play(events)`.

    Note: this is a blocking function. Note: for more details on the keyboard hook and events see `hook`.
    """
    start_recording()
    wait(until, suppress=suppress, trigger_on_release=trigger_on_release)
    return stop_recording()
```

So, to sum it up, what I want to achieve is a function that records the mouse movement until a keyboard event using the Python modules `mouse` and `keyboard`. 
Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to look at the implementation of ‘mouse’ or ‘keyboard’ as I suspect you will need to hook the system events yourself rather than using the libraries.

Comment: @MichaelD There is no need for creating system events. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge both without messing up with the module files:

1) Use `mouse.hook()` to record events without waiting (like it happens with `mouse.record()` ). It takes a function and return it that event.
2) Use `keyboard.wait(key)` to wait for the key to be pressed
3) Use `mouse.unhook()` to stop recording.

Here is an example code:

```
import mouse
import keyboard


events = []                 #This is the list where all the events will be stored
mouse.hook(events.append)   #starting the recording
keyboard.wait("a")          #Waiting for 'a' to be pressed
mouse.unhook(events.append) #Stopping the recording
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use threading to join keyboard and mouse together. The following code would record the mouse events and keyboard events and then play it back. You can stop monitoring by pressing Escape button.

```
import threading
import mouse
import keyboard

def monitorMouseKeyboardEvents():
    #These are the list where all the events will be stored
    mouse_events = []
    keyboard_events = []
    
    #Start recording
    mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)   #starting the mouse recording
    # keyboard.hook(lambda _: keyboard_events.append(_))
    keyboard.start_recording()
    
    keyboard.wait("esc")         #Waiting for 'Esc' button to be pressed
    
    #Stopping recording
    mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
    # keyboard.unhook(keyboard_events.append)
    keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording() 
    
    return mouse_events, keyboard_events


def playMouseMouseKeyboardEvents(mouse_events, keyboard_events):
    '''
    Playing the recorded events at the same time
    '''
    k_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :keyboard.play(keyboard_events))
    k_thread.start()
    
    #Mouse threadings:
    m_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :mouse.play(mouse_events))
    m_thread.start()    
    
    #waiting for both threadings to be completed
    k_thread.join() 
    m_thread.join()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mouse_events, keyboard_events=monitorMouseKeyboardEvents()
    playMouseMouseKeyboardEvents(mouse_events, keyboard_events)
```