# How to record mouse and keyboard movement simultaneously with Python?

Tags: python, keyboard, mouse

I want to create a function that records both mouse and keyboard events until a specific key is pressed and then replays them together.

I think that this can be achieved with the `keyboard` and `mouse` modules. In an earlier question, I asked [how to record the mouse movement until a key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57642617/how-to-record-the-mouse-movement-until-a-key-is-pressed-with-python?noredirect=1#comment101746612_57642617), and I got the following code:

```py
import mouse
import keyboard

events = []                 #This is the list where all the events will be stored
mouse.hook(events.append)   #starting the mouse recording
keyboard.wait("a")          #Waiting for 'a' to be pressed
mouse.unhook(events.append) #Stopping the mouse recording
mouse.play(events)          #Playing the recorded events
```

That works fine. As both modules were made by the same people, I assumed that the same would work with the keyboard module. But it doesn't.

```py
mouse_events = []
keyboard_events = []

mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard.hook(keyboard_events.append)

keyboard.wait("a")

mouse.unhook(events.append)
keyboard.unhook(events.append)
keyboard.play(events)
```

The `keyboard.hook(events.append)` line in the code above throws an error: 
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

I tried to check the module files but I fail to understand most of it.

So, to summarize: How can I start the mouse and keyboard recording at the same moment, stop them both at the same time and run both simultaneously? Are the `mouse` and `keyboard` modules the best option to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a problem with your code.
Your lists are:

```
mouse_events = []
keyboard_events = []
```

But you are using `events.append` rather than the list name. Looks like you forgot to modify the code.

---

The error is thrown because the module `keyboard` uses `dict` for `hook` unlike module `mouse` and you can't use `list` as keys.

You can solve this by using `lambda`:

```
keyboard.hook(lambda _: keyboard_events.append(_))
```

---

**There is more simpler way to do this** without using `hook` but its only for module `keyboard`

Use `start_recording()` and `stop_recording()`

**1)** `start_recording()` to enable the recording of keyboard events. It doesn't take a callback and you can record once at a time.
**2)** `stop_recording()` to stop the started recording. It returns the list of recorded events.

<sub>`mouse` module doesn't have `stop`/`start_recording`</sub>
So your final code will look like this:

```
import mouse
import keyboard

mouse_events = []


mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard.start_recording()       #Starting the recording

keyboard.wait("a")

mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording()  #Stopping the recording. Returns list of events
```

---

**Playing the events together:**

The only way to play both events at the same time is to use [`threading`](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Here is an example for your code:

```
import threading
import mouse
import keyboard

mouse_events = []


mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard.start_recording()

keyboard.wait("a")

mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording()

#Keyboard threadings:

k_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :keyboard.play(keyboard_events))
k_thread.start()

#Mouse threadings:

m_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda :mouse.play(mouse_events))
m_thread.start()

#waiting for both threadings to be completed

k_thread.join() 
m_thread.join()
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you play them together, at the same time? Using `mouse.play` and then `keyboard.play` is not what I expected to do. Any ideas?

Comment: @PauloSchreiner Its possible through `threading`. Check the edit

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: The events are out of sync tho, the mouse plays faster than the keyboard. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Wboy I am not sure but the possible reason is that modules are glitching

Comment: Hm i was thinking its due to the nature of the threads, the threads arent in sync 
 and the processor gives more time to a particular thread perhaps. the keyboard library doesnt seem to factor time of execution

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a [software](https://github.com/rmpr/atbswp) developed for this purpose, plus the events will be in sync, here is a GIF showcasing a basic use:

[image: atbswp]

In the background it creates a simple Python file with the modules [Pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) and the recording is done with [Pynput](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput)

Disclaimer: I am the author.