# How to correctly store user input (keyboard,mouse) in file using keyboard & mouse Python modules?

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard, mouse

I am using the keyboard and mouse modules to record user interaction with our software so that we can have some high level GUI tests.
Currently I am trying to store the recorded events in a text file and later play this recording again.

However when I load the recorded events from said file I only see played `mouse` events and **no** `keyboard` events.

One cause for this problem may be the implementation of KeyboardEvents. 
KeyboardEvents does not contain a correct implementation of `__repr__`. This prevents us from calling `print(keyboard_events, file=f)` and reading the lines with `eval(line)`. (This works with mouse and ButtonEvent and MoveEvent)
So we have decided to work with the json format of KeyboardEvents. Basically what we're doing is we retrieve the json format of each KeyboardEvent and write the json in the file. Then we load the json file and parse the json as KeyboardEvents.

Currently we're storing both mouse & keyboard input in a single file. However, since `mouse` supports a correct implementation of `__repr__` we can directly print and the mouse events and use `eval()` on it to retrieve the stored events.

This is the file used for recording and playing:

```py
import threading
import mouse
import keyboard

from mouse import ButtonEvent
from mouse import MoveEvent
from mouse import WheelEvent

from keyboard import KeyboardEvent

import time

import json
import sys

def record(file='record.txt'):
    f = open(file, 'w+')
    mouse_events = []
    keyboard_events = []
    keyboard.start_recording()
    starttime = time.time()
    mouse.hook(mouse_events.append)
    keyboard.wait('esc')
    keyboard_events = keyboard.stop_recording()
    mouse.unhook(mouse_events.append)
    #first line = start of recording
    #mouse events = second line
    #keyboard events = every remaining line = 1 event
    print(starttime, file=f)
    print(mouse_events, file=f)
    for kevent in range(0, len(keyboard_events)):
        print(keyboard_events[kevent].to_json(), file = f)
    f.close()

def play(file, speed = 0.5):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    #per definition the first line is mouse events and the rest is keyboard events
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    mouse_events = eval(lines[1])
    keyboard_events = []
    for index in range(2,len(lines)):
        keyboard_events.append(keyboard.KeyboardEvent(**json.loads(lines[index])))

    starttime = float(lines[0])
    keyboard_time_interval = keyboard_events[0].time - starttime
    keyboard_time_interval /= speed
    mouse_time_interval = mouse_events[0].time - starttime
    mouse_time_interval /= speed
    print(keyboard_time_interval)
    print(mouse_time_interval)
    #Keyboard threadings:
    k_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda : time.sleep(keyboard_time_interval) == keyboard.play(keyboard_events, speed_factor=speed) )
    #Mouse threadings:
    m_thread = threading.Thread(target = lambda : time.sleep(mouse_time_interval) == mouse.play(mouse_events, speed_factor=speed))
    #start threads
    m_thread.start()
    k_thread.start()
    #waiting for both threadings to be completed
    k_thread.join() 
    m_thread.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) > 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'play':
        play(sys.argv[2])
    elif len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'record':
        if(len(sys.argv)) == 3:
            record(sys.argv[2])
        else:
            record()
    else:
        print("missing either 'play' or 'record' or filename")
```

I expect the same behavior with this code like when it is run in a single function (see edit in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670484/7345513).

Meaning: I expect the playback in the threads to be synced and the keys to be pressed. What i actually get is that the mouse events are played back as desired but no KeyboardEvents are being processed. When I use the function from the linked SO it works.

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: You cannot rely on `repr(arbitrary_object)` to provide a representation that can be reversed with `eval()`. Therefore it's not an incorrect implementation as long as it returns a string. Third parties can return anything they want as `__repr__()`, so you can't even rely on `mouse` to always give you what you want in the future. `repr()` is a debugging tool, not fit for business logic. It would be better to rely on more robust serialization methods, such as JSON, XML, YAML, pickle or whatever your prefer.

Comment: `keyboard` already implements `KeyboardEvent.to_json()` as far as I can tell: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardeventto_jsonself-ensure_asciifalse
So this would likely be the easiest path forward if you want robustness.

Comment: I understand. But I am using the to_json() functionality already. 

My problem is that when I load the json string back to python the KeyboardEvents are not called. Maybe I am leading/writing them incorrectly? Everything I have is in the pasted source code...

Comment: Ok I have retried my code and basically tried to debug it within a single python session (usually this code will be started by calling `python record.py record`) and now both input is loaded. However the timings of `keyboard` seem to be off. I think this is due to it starting right off with its first input. This can be worked around... And I see now that not all input is forwarded to other applications. Which may be a bigger issue (ctrl+N i.e.)

Comment: I see. Sorry for not reading the code first. I was going by your descriptive text above.

Comment: Oh no worries. It became a much bigger wall of text than I wanted it to be. 
The code still does not do exactly what I want it to do but this may be some tweaking with the modules themselves. Have to do further reading on how to handle special input like ctrl+N and stuff.

Comment: The reason why the timing is not the way you expect it (i.e. the keyboard output starts too early) is that `record()` stores absolute timestamps (unix timestamps). Therefore, the only way for `play()` to play the events back is by playing the first event immediately, which is not what you want. To fix that, you will have to also keep a timestamp of when you started recording and then when you want to play the events back calculate `first_interval = keyboard_events[0].time - timestamp_when_recording_started` and use the result to `sleep(first_interval)` before calling `play()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I actually thought that something like this would be necessary. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to answer my own question but here it goes:

Thanks to the guidance from blubberdiblub I have tracked the start time for the tracking and can then add an offset to when the first input occurred. This allows playbacks to be timed somewhat accurately.